# ICanvasBitmap from BitmapSource

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmapsource, win2d

Is there a way to convert a Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource object into a member of a class that implements Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.ICanvasImage? The interface itself consists of just two rectangle-getting methods. However, I assume that's not enough, as my ultimate goal is to call

```
CanvasDrawingSession.DrawImage()
```

which I have to imagine requires a way to get at the bitmap pixels.

Comment: Where does your *BitmapSource* come from?

Comment: Splat library. https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat -- the fundamental issue that makes things hard is that I am developing for multiple platforms.  But I ended up deciding that this was messy enough that it was better to bypass the BitmapSource altogether in the case of Windows.

Comment: I ask, hence maybe it will be easier to use *SoftwareBitmap* instead of *BitmapSource*. Therefore it's straight away to create *CanvasImage* from it.

Comment: Well, the idea was that Splat loading hides the platform dependencies. But in this case, that's not going to fly, so I'm just getting it from the stream.

Comment: If you have a stream then you can probably use *SoftwareBitmap*: `BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
return await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);`. Then you can use *CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get pixel from Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.[BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) directly. But you can use a [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) instead of a BitmapImage. Then you can get pixel data via its [PixelBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx) property.

After that, you could use `CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes()` method to create CanvasBitmap. Then using this CanvasBitmap object as parameter to call `CanvasDrawingSession.DrawImage()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using *PixelBuffer*, as [described by Xavier Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054588/2681948) above, you may use *SoftwareBitmap* to create your *ICanvasImage*. If you have a stream then you can do this like this:

```
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
CanvasDrawingSession.DrawImage(await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied));
```